# Разместить li друг под другом вне зависимости от их высоты

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Имею следующий код:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

#test {
  position: static;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #03a9f4;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#test_2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  background: #eee;
}

.text {
  width: calc(100%  / 3);
  height: max-content;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #ccc6c6;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul id="test">
    <li>Меню 1</li>
    <li>Меню 2</li>
    <li>Меню 3</li>
    <li>Меню 4</li>
    <li>Меню 5</li>
    <li>Меню 6</li>
    <li>Меню 7</li>
    <li>Меню 8</li>
    <li>Меню 9</li>
    <li>Меню 10</li>
    <li>Меню 11</li>
    <li>Меню 12</li>
    <li>
      <a>Меню 13</a>
      <ul id="test_2">
        <li class="text">1. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">2. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">3. Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">4. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">5. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">6. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">7. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">8. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">9. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">10. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">11. Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">12. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">13. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">14. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">15. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо сделать, чтобы высота `li` автоматически подстраивалась под содержимое? Сейчас я использую `height: max-content;` - возможно это не лучший вариант. При этом, чтобы все `li` следовали сразу друг под другом, вне зависимости от высоты `li`, то есть:

[image: Пример 1]
[image: Пример 2]
[image: Пример 3]

Пытался ещё вместо `width: calc(100%  / 3);` использовать `column-count: 3;` - не получилось. Возможно кто-то сможет показать пример с использованием `column-count: 3;`

Высоту и ширину `#test`, а также ширину `#test_2`, пожалуйста, не изменяйте.

**Уточнение:** Необходимо, чтобы высота `#test_2` была по высоте `#test`.
Конструкцию `#test_2` можно сделать колоночной, также с использованием прокрутки.

Comment: Увы, пока что, CSS так не умеет, но слышал что **Masonry** будет. А пока, погуглите насчёт **Masonry grid** - в основном это JS библиотеки.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 с чего бы это css так не умеет?

Comment: @MichaelMiller, с того. Раскидывать как **Masonry** (слева-направо) CSS не умеет, а в варианте [@Инквизитор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1218509/221218) раскидывает сверху-вниз, а это другое.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, добавил уточнение, возможно при колоночной конструкции (сверху-вниз) что-то получится сделать:)

Comment: @Дмитрий, вот именно такой порядок делается благодаря скрипту **Masonry**

Answer (score 4):

`column-count: 3;` нужно применять не к `LI`, а к `UL`. И флексы отменить, с ними не получится. Но самое главное - конструкция получается колоночная и заполнение контентом будет не слева направо, а сверху вниз. Может, этого вам и достаточно будет:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

#test {
  position: static;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #03a9f4;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#test_2 {
  column-count: 3;
}

#test_2_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: auto;
}

.text {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: #ccc6c6;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu">
  <ul id="test">
    <li>Меню 1</li>
    <li>Меню 2</li>
    <li>Меню 3</li>
    <li>Меню 4</li>
    <li>Меню 5</li>
    <li>Меню 6</li>
    <li>Меню 7</li>
    <li>Меню 8</li>
    <li>Меню 9</li>
    <li>Меню 10</li>
    <li>Меню 11</li>
    <li>Меню 12</li>
    <li>Меню 13</li>
    <li id="test_2_wrapper">
      <ul id="test_2">
        <li class="text">1. Текст </li>
        <li class="text">2. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">3. Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">4. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">5. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">6. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">7. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">8. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">9. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">10. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">11. Текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">12. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">13. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">14. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
        <li class="text">15. Текст текст текст текст текст</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только в Вашем варианте `ul#test_2` выходит за размеры `ul#test` - хотелось бы, чтобы высота была, как в моём примере, при этом, чтобы блок `#test_2` имел прокрутку. Если сможете, поправьте, пожалуйста:) И можно ли отменить перенос 11 блока на 3 ряд?:) То есть, чтобы блоки полностью оставались в своих рядах, без переносов. В общем всё как у меня, только подтянуть `li` друг за другом. Конструкцию можно сделать колоночной

Comment: Если сделать высоту #test_2 как у #test_1, скролл будет горизонтальным ,а колонок будет много. Нужно обернуть #test_2 - я это сделал, тем более, что вы невалидно засунули `ul` сразу в `ul`. Чтобы блоки не переносились - посмотрите в сторону CSS-свойств break-inside и им подобных. Но тут никаких гарантий, что всеми браузерами они поддерживаются.

Comment: Да, действительно я неправильно указал вложение `ul` сразу в `ul`. В моём рабочем коде такой ошибки нет:) Поправил код в вопросе

Comment: В Вашем варианте, если `ul#test_2` поместить в `<li>Меню 13</li>`, задав соответственно этому `li` id `test_2_wrapper` - к сожалению, не подходит, "Меню 13" вылазит в область, где находится текст:(

Comment: Если возможно, поправьте, пожалуйста, свой вариант:)

Answer (score 1):

К `ul` добавить `css`

```
display:flex; align-items:flex-start; justify-content:flex-start
```

Comment: И что это дает?

Comment: @Инквизитор выравнивание элементов внутри flex родителя, в css flex есть куча свойств для этого, с такими мелочами никогда проблем не было. Если я неправильно понял вопрос, то тогда пардон за ответ. Но все же дал вроде логичный ответ.

Comment: Ответ вообще не по вопросу. И, самое интересное, абсолютно ничего в данной ситуации эти стиля не меняют...

Comment: @MichaelMiller, если правильно помню, то эти свойства вообще по умолчанию стоят.

Comment: Спасибо за уделённое время к моему вопросу:)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 да, но Вы можете использовать другие - **align-items:center; justify-content:space-between;** И так далее